# How to create an array with in_array() function?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, mysqli, associative-array

I am having problem with handling arrays. I  want to "compare" two arrays to see if there's matching "usernames" in both arrays. I am not sure if I am using in_array() function properly

this is how my arrays look like:

USER array 1:

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => LNDP [station] => D08 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [username] => ACMAN [station] => D06 )
        [2] => Array ( [username] => VTER [station] =>  D13 )
      )

    //the users will have to be matched with memo_code
    $user = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_user_result)){
        $user[] = array( "username" => $row['username'],
                         "station"  =>  $row['station_number']                                                          
                            );
    }
```

MEMO array 2:

```
 Array (   [0] => Array ( [username] => VTER[aht_value] =>  333 ) 
           [1] => Array ( [username] => ACMAN [aht_value] => 456 ) 
           [2] => Array ( [username] => ACYL [aht_value] =>  789 )
         )


$memo = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbh2_result)){   
        $memo[] = array( "username"  => $row['memo_code'],
                       "aht_value" => $row['avg_handle_time']
                      );
    }
```

I want to check every "username" in my MEMO array to match the "username" in my USER array.
If they do match, I want to create an array with username, station, aht_value like so:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => ACMAN [aht_value] => 456 [station] => D06 ) 
      )
```

what I tried:

//creating array 3 by comparing 1 and 2 by using key value of "username" from array 2
        $result = array();
        //$m = key
        //$m['username'] = key value
        foreach($memo as $m => $m['username']){

```
        //if username in array 2 is in array 1
        if( in_array( $m, $user) ){
            //if aht_value is not null
            if( $memo['aht_value'] != null ){
            $result[] =  "username: " . $user['username'] . "aht_value: " .$m['aht_value'] . "position: " . $user['position']. "<br>";   
            }
            //else if aht_value is null
            else{
                $result[] = "username: " . $user['username'] . "aht_value: NA  position: " . $user['position'] . "<br>";
            }
        }
        //if there is no matching username do something?
        else{
            echo "no match";
        }

    }

    $final_result = json_encode($result);
    echo $final_result;
```

If I need to clarify things please ask. After successfully creating the third array I will use json_encode to make an AJAX call and use type GET.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Error is pretty straightforward. You need to use something like `$username` in the => of the foreach, and then within the foreach pull things like `$username['username']`.

Comment: so this? **foreach($memo as $username => $user['username']){**  this gives me "no match" for everything in the loop

Comment: Nooo. `foreach($memo as $key => $value) { echo $value['username']; }`. Something like that.

Comment: too much codes. just give the two arrays and tell what you want to do.

Comment: `$m` is going to be a **KEY** from your array, which is just a string/int. YOu can't use that string/int as an array to assign the VALUE of the foreach.

Comment: What's your table structure and queries? This may be able to be done more efficiently with a JOIN.

Comment: @CurtisMattoon they are 2 different servers thats why I am combining both results into a single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$memo = array();
$result = array();
$user = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_user_result)) {
    $user[] = array(
        "username" => $row['username'],
        "station"  =>  $row['station_number']
    );
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbh2_result)) {   
    $memo[] = array(
        "username"  => $row['memo_code'],
        "aht_value" => $row['avg_handle_time']
    );
}

foreach ($memo as $i => $memodata) {
    foreach ($user as $j => $userdata) {
        if ($memodata['username'] == $userdata['username']) {
            if (is_null($memodata['aht_value'])) {
                $result[] = "username: " . $userdata['username'] . " aht_value: NA  position: " . $userdata['station'];
            } else {
                $result[] =  "username: " . $userdata['username'] . " aht_value: " .$memodata['aht_value'] . " position: " . $userdata['station'];   
            }
        } 
    }
}


echo json_encode($result);
```

This method isn't very efficient, because you have to loop through two arrays. A SQL JOIN might work better, or you could add a UNIQUE index to the arrays. (this won't work if the username is repeated, because associative arrays can't have duplicate keys)

```
<?php

$memo = array();
$result = array();
$user = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_user_result)) {
    $user[$row['username']] = array(
        "username" => $row['username'],
        "station"  =>  $row['station_number']
    );
}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbh2_result)) {   
    $memo[$row['memo_code']] = array(
        "username"  => $row['memo_code'],
        "aht_value" => $row['avg_handle_time']
    );
}

foreach ($memo as $username => $memodata) {
    if (in_array($username, array_keys($user))) {
        // Match username against the keys of $user (the usernames) */
        $userdata = $user[$username];
        if (is_null($memodata['aht_value'])) {
            $result[] = "username: " . $userdata['username'] . "aht_value: NA  position: " . $userdata['position'] . "<br>";
        } else {
            $result[] =  "username: " . $userdata['username'] . "aht_value: " .$m['aht_value'] . "position: " . $userdata['position']. "<br>";   
        }
    }
}


echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: I tried both of your ways and modified stuff as well but I keep getting  a bunch of results and error messages like : **Undefined index: position in line 175** being **    $result[] = "username: " . $userdata['username'] . "aht_value: NA  position: " . $userdata['position'] . "<br>";**  it is also skipping the ELSE statement. It only goes to the "IF".

Comment: That means the key 'position' isn't found in the array. It's in your output, but neither of your example arrays have it.

Comment: Can you `var_dump` your real arrays? Like, the entire structure? Try pastebin if they're huge.

Comment: this is [user array](http://pastebin.com/jwhrMhzN) and this is [memo array](http://pastebin.com/45V4vf6Y)

Comment: How could I make these two conditions: If theres a match in usernames but "aht_value" is null then do something.. elseif theres a match in usernames and "aht_value" is not null do something.. maybe I need those conditions in order for the loop to work?

Comment: That's what `if (is_null($memodata['aht_value']))` tests for, but only if `$username` is in the keys of `$user`. (Did you change the way the arrays are generated? `$memo[$row['memo_code']] = array...`)

Comment: what do you mean if I change how the arrays are generated? I keep using your first answer with only one "Foreach" loop and it still complains about **unidintified index position** but why if position does exist in my user array? thanks

Comment: Oh. In the first answer, the `$user` should be changed to `$userdata` for the `$result` part.

Comment: can you edit it? Im getting all confused lol sorry.. I mean I was using your 2nd answer since thats where theres only ONE FOREACH loop

Comment: ok so the first answer is working I just had to edit something extra. However the second answer crashes with error messages and by the end of it it outputs the results but only going to the ELSE statement, any ideas? thanks

Comment: I am getting the error message the number of times of the array length.. is it because it has duplicate keys like you said?

Comment: The "error" is a `Notice`, and is because you still have `position` as an array key. Change it to `station` or whatever exists in your array. it's `position` in my answer because it was `position` in your original code.

Comment: awesome man! can't thank you enough now it works like I want it to! was hard to understand how key values work. Appreciate your help!! :D

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, this should achieve what you want:

```
$data = array()
foreach($memo as $m){
    foreach($user as $u){
        if($m['username']===$u['username']){
            $m['station'] = $u['station'];
            $data[] = $m;
        }
    }
}
```

But if I were you, I would manage to merge the records using an SQL JOIN on the username or id so that only one query is executed.

Comment: I had a loop a similar to that before but I want to make a single for loop. Theres no "station" in memo array so how can you compare it to $u['station']? thanks

Comment: read my code carefully, username is being compare, and station is appended to memo

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php   

    function inUserArray($userArray, $username)
    {   
        foreach($userArray as $user)
        {
            if($user['username'] == $username)
            {
                return $user;
            }
        }

        return array();
    }


    foreach($memo as $m){

        //if username in array 2 is in array 1
        $user = inUserArray($user, $m);
        if( !empty($user) ){
            //if aht_value is not null
            if( $m['aht_value'] != null ){
            $result[] =  "username: " . $user['username'] . "aht_value: " .$m['aht_value'] . "position: " . $user['position']. "<br>";   
            }
            //else if aht_value is null
            else{
                $result[] = "username: " . $user['username'] . "aht_value: NA  position: " . $user['position'] . "<br>";
            }
        }
        //if there is no matching username do something?
        else{
            echo "no match";
        }

    }          
?>
```

Comment: I tried your code but the output I get is **[]** any ideas? thanks